# Android-Kotlin - TimePickerDialog shows incorrect time when set programatically

Tags: android, kotlin, datetimepicker, timepicker

I am setting a default time in my code and wish to set the time picker dialog to that time when the user clicks on it. Below is the code:

```
startTimeButton?.setOnClickListener {
            val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
            val timeSetListener = TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener { view, hourOfDay, minute ->
                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay)
                calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute)
                startTimeButton?.text = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(calendar.time)
                SharedPreferences.setStartTime(activity, startTimeButton?.text.toString())
            }

            val startTimeArray: List<String> = SharedPreferences.getStartTime(context).split(":")
            TimePickerDialog(activity, timeSetListener, calendar.get(startTimeArray[0].toInt()), calendar.get(startTimeArray[1].toInt()), true).show()
        }
```

If my start time is 09:00, the time picker dialog points to 01:01 and if it's 17:00, then time picker dialog crashes with "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=17; index=17" error.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The `get()` function on `Calendar`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar#get(int)) returns a value for a given field identifier. Examples include `calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)` and `calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE)`.

You appear to be passing into `get()` hours and minutes as integers. Those are not field identifiers.

I suspect that this is closer to what you want:

```
TimePickerDialog(activity, timeSetListener, startTimeArray[0].toInt(), startTimeArray[1].toInt(), true).show()
```

Also, please make sure you are handling configuration changes. For example, use a `DialogFragment` to show your `TimePickerDialog`.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the code and it fixed the issue. Could you let me know why do I need to use a dialogFragment to show time picker dialog? Right now I am just clicking on a button which opens up default TimePickerDialog. I learnt this on a tutorial and using the same.

Comment: @tech_human: "Could you let me know why do I need to use a dialogFragment to show time picker dialog?" -- as I wrote, you need to be to able to handle configuration changes. See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes) or any decent book on Android app development.